# How to force pig to increase map quantity

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I have a task which is highly parallelizable. In hadoop I could write a task to use all server capacity. However Pig just runs 1 map.

The task is very simple, I load a set of ints (120k in total) and then process each of them separately in a udf. Something like

```
LOAD data as (id:int);
result = foreach data generate udf.myFunction(id);
STORE result ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pig will estimate the amount of splits (-> amount of mappers) based on the input size.

You can decrease the max split size to get more mappers.

```
SET mapred.max.split.size #bytes
```